# MX Title Control - Not working with EE 2.8.0?

Tags: mx-title-control

I've just set up a new testing environment and a brand new copy if EE 2.8 for testing new Add-Ons. After installing the latest MX Title Control (2.8.4) i can't seem to get it to work.

I've never had any problems with MX Title Control with older versions of EE.

Anyone experiencing the same problem?

Comment: I'm also noticing that MX Title Control 2.8.4 is not working in ExpressionEngine 2.8.1. Would be great if the developer issued a fix for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The awesome Eric Lamb helped me track down the fix for this problem. It isn't related to the CP URL change. It's a problem in the addon file.

Change line 326 from:

```
$out = '//  THIS IS TEST';
```

to this:

```
$out = '';
```

Comment: This fix worked for me using MXTC 2.9.0 and EE 2.9.0

Comment: oh... so silly from my side :( In my local repository I don't have this line, and all other lines is the same. It is why MXTC works fine on my installs and clients... My apology for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the plugin by updating the ext.mx_title_control.php file on line 333 and 338. I replaced the following code:

element('channel_id', $get)

with

element('/cp/content_publish/entry_form?channel_id', $get)

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Have you sent this fix to Max Lazar? He may incorporate it into his code to get a fixed version out there.

Comment: I did as suggested, but strangely it didn't work for me. I'm using MXTC 2.9.0 on EE 2.8.1 at the moment. Tried deactivating Zenbu but didn't help either.

Comment: This fix worked for me

Comment: Didn't work for me either with MXTC 2.9.0 on EE 2.8.1

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of Javascript related issues surfacing with 2.8, and I believe MX Title Control is highly JS-dependent, so this isn't surprising.

You might try applying the patch posted on this Bug Tracker: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20165

Comment: Thanks for the hint, sadly it didn't help. I believe a fix from the developer is required.

Comment: yes and no - the most important, that they change they URL's structure. before: &D=cp&C=content_publish& after:/cp/content_publish/entry_form; it is broke trick with HTTP_REFERER  for cp_js_end

Comment: @MaxLazar Can MX Title Control not be fixed to work with 2.8.1?

Answer (score 1):

This thread is a few months old, but the solutions provided so far have not worked for me. Until MX Title Control is updated for 2.8.1 (it still isn't as of posting), a simple fix to modify the "Title" and  "URL Title" labels is to simply add some JS within the "instructions" field of any field within that channel's field group:

```
<script>// We're using this field's instructions to hijack labels via JS at DOM-ready
$(function() {

    // Make sure that this is the publish form (just for a level of safety)
    if (!EE.publish) return;
    // Set your channel's field group here (just another level of safety)
    if (EE.publish.field_group == 4) {

        // "Title" Label
        var titleLabel = $("#sub_hold_field_title").prev("label")
        var titleMarkup = titleLabel.html();
        titleLabel.html(titleMarkup.replace('Title','Custom Title'));

        // "URL Title" Label
        var URLTitleLabel = $("#sub_hold_field_url_title").prev("label")
        var URLTitleMarkup = URLTitleLabel.html();
        URLTitleLabel.html(URLTitleMarkup.replace('URL Title','Custom URL Title'));

    } else return;
});</script>
```

It's less than elegant, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else stumbles on this looking for an answer, when upgrading isn't possible, change line 328:

```
parse_str(parse_url(@$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY), $get);
```

to

```
parse_str(parse_url(parse_url(@$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], PHP_URL_QUERY), PHP_URL_QUERY), $get);
```

The URLs in 2.8 add an additional "?" to the query string (e.g. "/system/index.php?/cp/content_publish/entry_form?channel_id=22") because of this the `parse_url` function doesn't properly parse the URL and thus creates issues for the rest of the `cp_js_end` function.

Also worth noting is that line 432 should also be updated to work with the new input field format (i.e. the removal of the ID attribute).

change line 432 from:

```
$out .= '$("#title").attr("maxlength", "'.$max_title.'");';
```

to

```
$out .= '$("[name=\'title\']").attr("maxlength", "'.$max_title.'");';
```