# Seeking an alternative to Title Master that is compatible with 2.9

Tags: safecracker, title-master

Does anyone know of an add-on that offers the same functionality of Title Master but which is compatible with EE 2.9?

If you aren't familiar with Title Master I need something that will auto populate entry titles with an incremental value, prefixed by the value of another field (in this case an entry-id from a relationship field). This also needs to happen on the front end via a Channel Form.

Big ask, but it was working perfectly with Title Master until I updated the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not have all the features you need, but just in case, [MX Title Control](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-title-control) works in EE 2.9.0 if you have the latest version (2.9) and apply the [fix in this thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/19974/mx-title-control-not-working-with-ee-2-8-0).

Comment: I've accepted this as it seems to be a reasonable alternative. But in the end I think I managed to work around the requirement for Title Master